# Distinguishing Between 'Periodically' and 'Sporadically': Usage and Differences

Tags: meaning, word-usage, word-choice, difference, vocabulary

I've encountered some confusion while trying to differentiate between the terms "periodically" and "sporadically." Both seem to relate to the frequency of events, but I'm unsure about how they are distinct in their usage and connotation. My questions are as follows:

What is the fundamental difference in meaning between "periodically" and "sporadically"?

Are there specific contexts where one term is more appropriate than the other?

Comment: "Periodically=In a regular manner" ,"sporadically=Not in a regular manner/sometimes"

Comment: How fundamental do you want to go?  A deep understanding of the root words?  Periodic/periodically: regularly/at regular time intervals, from Late Latin periodicus "that returns at stated intervals of time", from Greek periodos (a cycle, a circuit, an interval of time) from Greek peri- (around) + hodos (way/path/journey).  Sporadic/sporadically: at random times/scattered - ultimately from Greek sporadikos "scattered" - Greek root: spora (a seed/the sowing of seeds), also the root of the English word "spore".  Think of spores scattering in the wind!

Answer (score 4):

"Periodically" often is used to refer specifically to something that occurs regularly, for example, [journals, newspapers, or magazines](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Periodical_literature) can be described as being published ***periodically***. As shown by these examples, something with a regular schedule can be described as "periodical" regardless of whether it is frequent or infrequent: an annual publication is just as periodical as a weekly or daily one.

Sometimes the word "periodically" is used more loosely to refer to something that occurs repeatedly but not at set intervals; for example, when describing a person's behavior (just as we might say someone "regularly" does something when describing behavior that is habitual but does not occur at a strict schedule). Like similar words or phrases, such as "habitually", "regularly", "from time to time", "now and then", this usage has no particularly clear definition: what it means will depend on the context.

"Sporadically" cannot be used to describe something that has a regular schedule. It implies that the event described happened or happens more than once, but irregularly. I would say that it generally connotes that the event is infrequent as well as at least somewhat unpredictable.